# COUNT(*) and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

This query:

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, COUNT(references_table.staff_id) 
FROM staff 
LEFT JOIN references_table USING (staff_id)
```

returns this:

```
staff_id    COUNT(references_table.staff_id)
1            2
```

How can I get it to return 0 as the count for `staff_ids` that don't have any references?

Answer (score 5):

a `GROUP BY` clause will do the trick

```
SELECT staff.staff_id, COUNT(references_table.staff_id) 
FROM staff 
LEFT JOIN references_table USING (staff_id)
GROUP BY staff.staff_id
```

Comment: Upvoting yours.  It's a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try a left outer join.

Comment: 'OUTER' in 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' is redundant in MySQL syntax

Comment: I was under the impression that LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN were synonymous.

Comment: My bad.  I didn't see the MySql tag.